# got error at parsed.map((e) => list.add(e)).toList(); . how im gonna parsed the json file?

Tags: json, flutter, dictionary, dart, tolist

based on code below, the error state on parsed.map is "The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'String'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'map'."

and at parsed.map((e) is "Missing parameter type for 'e'.
Try adding an explicit type, or remove implicit-dynamic from your analysis options file."

```
 List<Map<String, dynamic>> parseResponse(String responsebody) {
    String responseBody;
    final parsed =
        json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>() as String;
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> list = [];
    parsed.map((e) => list.add(e)).toList();
    return list;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`as String` makes `parsed` a `String`, so try removing that.